# Simultaneously switch tags as one screen in multi monitor setup in 3.5?

Tags: multiple-monitors, awesome-wm

The answer propsed in [Simultaneously switch tags as one screen in multi monitor setup](https://superuser.com/questions/556877/simultaneously-switch-tags-as-one-screen-in-multi-monitor-setup/556931#556931)

is not working in awesome 3.5. Any solutions?

Since I' m new to awesome and lua, I don' t know how to do it myself. And I have no right to comment on the anwser. Sorry for restarting a question.

Comment: I left a comment for you. You might also want to post a comment in the forum thread where the answer was obtained from. If you manage to solve the problem don't forget to post an answer below.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out there is the original post. The original post was for 3.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awful.key({ modkey, "Control"   }, "Left", 
function()
    for i = 1, screen.count() do
        awful.tag.viewprev(i)
    end
end ),

awful.key({ modkey, "Control"   }, "Right", 
function()
    for i = 1, screen.count() do
        awful.tag.viewnext(i)
    end
end ),
```

Found on the original post for 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness here's the change for the 1..9 keys:

```lua
awful.key({ modkey }, "#" .. i + 9,
    function ()
        for screen = 1, screen.count() do
            local tag = awful.tag.gettags(screen)[i]
            if tag then
                awful.tag.viewonly(tag)
            end
        end
    end
),
```

And to handle the click on the taglist:

```lua
mytaglist.buttons = awful.util.table.join(
  awful.button({ }, 1, function(tag)
    local i = awful.tag.getidx(tag)
    for screen = 1, screen.count() do
        local tag = awful.tag.gettags(screen)[i]
        if tag then
           awful.tag.viewonly(tag)
        end
    end
  end),
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

For Awesome version 4.3 now in the year 2023 this can be accomplished with the following changes in rc.lua to use modkey+# to switch tags on all screens at once:

```
-- View tag only.
        awful.key({ modkey }, "#" .. i + 9,
                  function ()
             for s in screen do
                   --local screen = awful.screen.focused()
                           local tag = screen[s].tags[i]
                            if tag then
                             tag:view_only()
                            end
                    end
           end,
                  {description = "view tag #"..i, group = "tag"}),
```